# Kubernetes working with java long running tasks

Tags: java, kubernetes

I have a long running task length 10-20 hours that imports data in the database.
I am thinking about creating a table to check if its still running and that no one could rerun the task until the last one is finished .I thought doing it by creating a table and updating it at the beginning and end of the task. But for example, if Pod gets OOMKilled or someone restarts it in the middle of the task it won't update it.

Does anyone has successions how to update the table on pod restarts or deletion ?

Comment: You could create a table with a single row try locking the row before starting to import. The lock should be unlocked if the pod dies, and at most one pod can obtain the lock at once.

Comment: try using prometheus and grafana monitoring. You can not only live monitor the state but also other low level metrics.